# Display bitmap of any size in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to display a bitmap read from the SD card at **actual pixel size** in Android.

I can't assume anything about the bitmap, other than Android supports its image format. The bitmap might be huge.

Seems simple enough, but when you factor Android memory limitations it gets much more complicated.

Any ideas?

**Edit**: Attempting to load a large bitmap gives an out of memory error because Android is not able to allocate enough memory to decode it. You can load a scaled down version of the bitmap, but this is not useful to show the bitmap at actual pixel size. The question is about how to show a large bitmap on Android while staying within the app's memory constraints (most likely by loading it in chunks).

**Edit 2**: The bitmap might be huge, but within the realm of reasonable. I'm talking about user images, not HD Nasa pictures.

Comment: Well, tried what exactly?  You tried to load a large bitmap and it failed to display at all, even minimized?

Comment: The question is about showing a bitmap in actual pixel size. If you've got 16MB at most for the whole app, it's evident that any large bitmaps will cause an out of memory error. If by "minimized" you mean scaling it down with BitmapFactory, that's another thing entirely (with its own problems).

Comment: You tried to load a > ~16MB bitmap and you got an OS error when you even attempt to bring it onto screen even scaled down? You tried to scale it up to actual size and then drew an error? Tell us what exactly you're doing that draws an error.

Comment: Attempting to load a large bitmap gives an out of memory error because Android is not able to allocate enough memory to decode it. You can load a scaled down version of the bitmap, but this is not what the question is about. It's about how to show a large bitmap on Android while staying within the app's memory constraints (most likely by loading it in chunks).

Comment: Pardon the questions, but I've never attempted what you're doing, so the questions may seem off point, but aren't.

When you say you can load a "scaled down version," do you mean a < ~16MB file?

Comment: No worries, user225626. By "scaled down version" I mean telling BitmapFactory the scaling factor that it should apply to the bitmap while loading it. The allows you to decode a smaller bitmap than the source.

Comment: there's a discussion on a android dev group with similar question: 
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/756cbb328ddff458
which also links to http://groups.google.com.hk/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3c12a6fb1a46e910/55f76d394266d675?q=#55f76d394266d675

Comment: Thanks Mathias. It seems those programmers want to show a specific HUGE image, and they can pre-process it. In my case, I want to deal with user images (they won't as big) and I don't know them beforehand. But yes, I suspect loading it in chunks is the only way.

Comment: This was a good question, did you ever figure out the answer? I was thinking something along the lines of loading chunks as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since android 2.3 (Gingerbread, API Level 10), you can use the [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://d.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html). I don't know any solution for older android versions. (and I've been looking for it for my EmailAlbum app)

Answer (score 3):

The managed code (Java) has memory limits of 16/24/32MB even if your device has a lot more free memory.  I'm currently working on an application which needs to do this and the solution is to allocate the bitmap in native code (NDK) and then render views of the image into a Java-allocated bitmap which is the size of the display.  In native code you can allocate all available memory of the device, but for some reason the virtual machine limits it.

Comment: In your C code, you will use malloc() to allocate the memory for the large bitmap.  On the Java side you will create a bitmap object the size of the window.  You will have to write your own bitblit routine to copy the visible section of the large bitmap into the window-sized bitmap.  You can get a pointer to the bits of a Java Bitmap by calling AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() from your C code (Android 2.2+). Beyond these details is starting to encroach on my proprietary work.

Comment: Oh! and I dont need to write my own bitblit routine. I used the skia lib already available in android.